# Batch to get systeminfo for Multi remote windows servers

Tags: windows, batch-file, filesysteminfo

I'm trying to make a batch file to run the systeminfo command.

I am using this command for one server and it's working but I need for multiple servers.

> SYSTEMINFO /S ServerName /U My_Domain\my_domain_account /p
>   my_password >C:\Systeminfo.txt

I couldn't use powershell, we have **windows server 2003, 2008 and 2008R2.**

I need to check Registered Owner and Registered Organization but would be great to have output like above command.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your list of servers in a text file, one server name per line. Then create a .cmd file that looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
for /f %%s in ('type "serverlist.txt"') do call :PROCESS %%s
goto :END

:PROCESS
systeminfo /s %1 > %1.txt
goto :EOF

:END
endlocal
```

When you run this script you will have .txt files with system info for each server.

Comment: I should put domain and domain account on batch file.
Also could I use csv and put all servers in one csv file?

Comment: The shell script (.cmd batch file) solution does not use a CSV file. The above code assumes a file called serverlist.txt that contains a list of server name, one server name per line.

Comment: @echo off setlocal enableextensions for /f %%s in ('type "servers.txt"') do call :PROCESS %%s goto :END :PROCESS SYSTEMINFO /S %1 /U domain\account /P password /FO CSV > C:\systeminfo.csv goto :EOF :END endlocal I changed your script, the output is last server name.

so it should check one server, save it and then go to the next one, all of them in one output.

Comment: If you write `> C:\systeminfo.csv`, the CSV file will contain information for only the last server in the list. You could write `>> C:\systeminfo.csv`, but then you will have to edit the CSV file afterwards to remove all of the duplicated header lines.

Comment: Instead I would recommend `/CSV /NH >> C:\systeminfo.csv` to omit the header lines.